# Writing compressed html from python3

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to write a python script that can be run from a browser and displays a very basic html page.
When I use a multiline code block for the html code the web page displays fine.

When i run the script below in a browser from the cgi-bin folder it displays a blank page. Is there a way to do it in a single line?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

str="test"
print("<html><head></head><body><h1>Sample string:", str, "</h1></body></html>")
```

The code below is to start the python server that serves the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import http.server
import socketserver
import cgitb

# debugging via de web browser
cgitb.enable(format="text")

Handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler

PORT = 8000

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.server_name = ""
httpd.server_port = PORT

print("serving at port", PORT)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Why is the HTML code not working? Also, you should never use `str` as the name of a variable.

Comment: What? You are mentioning multiline code, but your HTML is only in a single line. Also printing text does not write a file, so I’m not sure what you are expecting here.

Comment: The output of this program is perfectly fine. It does what you'd expect, and the html code is correct. What problem, _precisely_, are you running into?

Comment: I don't understand. Your code works, print all HTML tags with "test" string inside. What's the matter?

Comment: I forgot to mention i serve this page from the cgi-bin and try to run this from a browser , I updated the question

Comment: You mention you want to run this in a browser. Browsers don't generally support python. I expect you want to run this on a server and then have the server respond with the output of the python script. This requires a specific server setup. Do you have a local server running? And if so, how is it set up? We don't have enough information to answer your question at the moment.